# into "a" or "the" wall?

Tags: grammar, definite-article, indefinite-article

> As soon as Tom stepped into the room, Pete shoved him against a/the wall.

In writing would native speakers be more inclined to use the definite article here even though we don't know which of the four walls of the room it is?

Comment: Neither. Native speakers would identify the wall in question, and then use *the* (for example: the opposite wall). Otherwise it sounds like Pete picked a wall randomly or the room had only one wall.

Comment: Both are fine. But in practice, I'm quite sure *most* native speakers would use ***the** wall* rather than ***a** wall* in the cited context - even though obviously most rooms have ***four*** walls, and it's vanishingly unlikely there's any prior context identifying ***the specific wall*** that someone got pushed against. Which just goes to show there's a limit to how useful the idea of only using the ***definite*** article for ***something previously mentioned*** is.

Comment: [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pushed+me+against+the+wall%2Cpushed+me+against+a+wall&year_start=1979&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpushed%20me%20against%20the%20wall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpushed%20me%20against%20a%20wall%3B%2Cc0) a relevant usage chart.

Comment: Also: Tackling usually means throwing someone to the ground. Tackling into a wall sounds strange.

Comment: @EthanBolker Pete obviously has poor tackle technique.

Comment: Pete's poor head!  Since the word "tackled" is not material to the point of the question, I think I'll change it, to make it easier to answer. Go ahead and revert if that is wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, [slap]!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, just to be clear: your comment is spot on and definitely of full answer quality (it's currently at+5!) I actually spent a wee while going over meta to see if there was a way to promote good comments to answers, but short of being a Diamond mod, I don't think there is. And my tongue-in-cheek attempt at doing it by **referring** to your comment from my own answer just got deleted, so that got us nowhere. Seriously though, as a last attempt, your stuff is very good, so please use answers more often. It'll make for a better ell.se overall 

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Here's why.

Where conversations involve more than 2 people, and articles are used, use of *the* means *everyone* should know which X, and those that don't will have to ask questions to catch up, or just remember that you don't know which X and need to pay attention to get that information when you can.

In fiction, sometimes the conversation includes you as the reader, the narrator, and the characters in the story.

> As soon as Tom stepped into the room, Pete shoved him against a/the wall.

So Pete knows which wall is the wall, and so did Tom (if he didn't, he knows now).

You the reader don't know, but all the writer thinks you need to know right now is that Tom wasn't shoved into any random wall, but rather a wall that both Tom and Pete knew about.