# the wall or a wall when describing a room (again as answer is not clear)

Tags: grammar, definite-article, indefinite-article

I've read [into "a" or "the" wall?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/280067/into-a-or-the-wall) and https://grammargeddon.com/2020/02/21/a-wall-or-the-wall-does-it-matter/. The question arose due to a text in English Students book.

> There are pictures on the wall.
> There's a carpet on the floor.

As I've read the linked explanations above, the wall is more common even as the text does not specify which wall it is. Please somebody explain (confirm): is it just how it is spoken without any particular rule?
If not, can one also write "There is the carpet on the floor" (first time mentioning that carpet) assuming the narrator knows which carpet it is?

Answer (score 1):

The single line must occur in a context such as:

> A: Tell me about your room.
>
> B: There is a picture on the wall...

The difference is that having previously established that we are talking about a room, there is a shared understanding that "rooms have walls and floors".  So B can refer to "the wall", to mean "the wall that surrounds the room". But not all rooms have pictures. So "... a picture...".

The wall does not need to be explicitly mentioned before, because the mention of a room implies mention of the wall and the floor.

But not all rooms have carpets, so "There is the carpet..." is odd.  Particularly as if you need to say "There is..." then you assume that the other person doesn't know about the carpet.

But it would be reasonable to say:

> A: Tell me about your room.
>
> B: The carpet is blue.

Comment: thanks. you did not explain second example with "the carpet". does it assume there is only one carpet in the room?

Comment: It means that the speaker knows, and believes that the listener also knows, that there is one carpet in the room (as would be common in rooms with fitted carpets)